# User Email Id is showing null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want to assign Logged in User Email id in obj.UserEmailId and pass it in View() but it's showing null. Hovering on User.Identity.Name shows UserEmailId but I don't know why obj.UserEmailId is showing null. Please refer to below image link and Code.

[image: Showing User.Identity.Name]

[image: Showing after assigning obj.UserEmailid is null]

[image: EventModel.cs file]

Comment: If the user id is for the connected user then it's better to never get from your form. Always get from Identity.Name

Comment: @CodeNotFound Thanks for replying. Yeah I got it but I need to do some operations in the View therefore I want to pass it.

Comment: Everything is fine. Just move breackpoint to the next line

Comment: at that point of your code, `obj.UserEmailId` has not yet been assigned. Hit f10 to move to next line and re-inspect